# How to use Pusher private channel authorization with Parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, pusher

I didn't find anything useful on the internet about this, so I want to share.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Client:

```
var pusher = new Pusher('your-app-key', {authTransport: 'parse'});

Pusher.authorizers.parse = function (socketId, callback) {
    var pusherData = { 
        socket_id: socketId, 
        channel_name: this.channel.name 
    };
    Parse.Cloud.run('authorizePusherChannel', pusherData, {
        success: function (result) {
            callback(false, JSON.parse(result));
        },
        error: function (error) {
            callback(true, error);
        }
    });
};
```

On Parse Cloud:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('authorizePusherChannel', function (request, response) {
    if (!request.user) { response.error('User should be autenticated.'); }
    var pusherAppKey = 'your-pusher-app-key';
    var pusherAppSecret = 'your-pusher-app-secret';
    var stringToSign = request.params.socket_id + ':' + request.params.channel_name;
    var authToken = pusherAppKey + ':' + crypto.createHmac('sha256', pusherAppSecret).update(stringToSign).    digest('hex');    
    response.success(JSON.stringify({auth:authToken}));
});
```

Comment: I think there's a part missing here which sets the authorizer to use the `parse` one.

Comment: @leggetter you're right! Added it on the answer. Thanks!

Comment: This is not working for me.  The endpoint is called (confirmed by parse console debugging).  The response looks to be a valid auth keyed json...However an error spits out in pusher console: "Auth info required to subscribe to private-chat"

Answer (score 0):

```
Pusher.authorizers.parse = function (socketId, callback) {
    var pusherData = { 
        socket_id: socketId, 
        channel_name: this.channel.name 
    };
    Parse.Cloud.run('authorizePusherChannel', pusherData, {
        success: function (result) {
            callback(false, JSON.parse(result));
        },
        error: function (error) {
            callback(true, error);
```